# Windows Showing Access Denied Error to Folders I Own

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, windows-live

I logged on to my computer today and wanted to remove a program from my *start up* folder which I placed there a few months ago. While navigating there, I got an error on the *start up* folder that stated "Access Denied".  Turns out that this is the case for *all hidden files and folders* for my account *which are owned by it*.

Theres only one thing I can think that caused this: Last week, on the live.com website, I updated my profile picture and turned on two-step verification for my  account. I know that it's tied to Windows log in, so I'm suspecting something happened there to cause this. (My user log in image did change to reflect the live.com change)

MS Support Desk is of no help, of course, so I figured that I'd ask here.

Does anyone know what happened and know how to fix it?

Screenshot of the issue is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0SFu.png).

Also Admin `CMD` [can't access it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fXe3.png).

(Sorry for the links: Not yet 10 rep. on SU.)

Comment: I should also note that, during Windows installation, I moved some home folders to a second drive. (I.E.: Downloads, Pictures, Documents, etc.)  But I kept the important ones on the main drive.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest editing Security to allow permissions for "Everyone" but I gather from the screenshot that you've already tried this and inevitably it failed.

Although I'm not sure of the exact cause, one possible solution could be to try and install [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html).